# Using the Interactive Brokers, Python, API, How to Buy / Sell Fractional Shares?

Tags: python-3.x, api, interactive-brokers, tws

Using the tws Python api code, I can buy / sell stocks: https://interactivebrokers.github.io/tws-api/-

I am using the placeOrder() function call:

```
contact = Contract()
contract.stock = "AAPL"
contract.secType = "STK"
contract.exchange = "SMART"
contract.currency = "USD"

order = Order()
order.action = "BUY"
order.totalQuantity = 1
order.orderType = "MKT"

placeOrder(self, orderId:OrderId , contract:Contract, order:Order)
```

However, when I place a fractional shares order, it fails.

What do I need to add in order to support fractional shares?

Comment: Include the full error message, we don't know what "it fails" is as it's impossible to diagnose.

Comment: As @misantroop said, you should provide a more informative question.  An API request never 'fails'  (provide it makes it to the API).  IB API will always provide an error message callback that tells you what went wrong. That's the first place to look.  You should also consider which version of the API you are using as fractional shares is only supported in v10 forward.